# Button title overwritten with cell refresh

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I am refreshing one cell when a button is clicked with this line of code...

```
self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
```

For some reason some of the times you click the button it reverts it back to the original title in the storyboard. Here is the entire button function just in case if this helps...

```
 var liked = [Bool]()

func like(sender: AnyObject) {

    var buttonPosition: CGPoint = sender.convertPoint(CGPointZero, toView: self.table)

    var indexPath: NSIndexPath = self.table.indexPathForRowAtPoint(buttonPosition)!

    if liked[indexPath.row] == true {

        var removeLikeQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

        removeLikeQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: self.messages[indexPath.row])

        removeLikeQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (rPosts, error) -> Void in
            if let rPosts = rPosts {
                for rPost in rPosts {
                    rPost.removeObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")
                    rPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (b, e) -> Void in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                            sender.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)
                        })
                    })

                }
            }
        }

        self.liked[indexPath.row] = false

    } else {

        var addLikeQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

        addLikeQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: self.messages[indexPath.row])

        addLikeQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (aPosts, error) -> Void in
            if let aPosts = aPosts {
                for aPost in aPosts {
                    aPost.addUniqueObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!, forKey: "likers")
                    aPost.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (b, e) -> Void in
                        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                            self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
                            sender.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal)

                        })
                    })


                }
            }
        }

        self.liked[indexPath.row] = true

    }

    println("liked = \(liked)")


}
```

In the cellForRowAtIndexPath I have...

```
       var postsQuery = PFQuery(className: "Post")

        postsQuery.whereKey("message", equalTo: self.messages[indexPath.row])

        postsQuery.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (posts, error) -> Void in
            if let posts = posts {
                for post in posts {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                        if self.liked.count < self.messages.count {
                            if (post["likers"] as! NSMutableArray).containsObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                                self.liked.append(true)
                                postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)

                            } else {
                                self.liked.append(false)
                            }
                        }

                        postCellObj.numberOfLikes.text = (post["likers"] as! [String]).count.description + " Likes"

                    })
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Show us your tableview datasource

Comment: @JasonNam The code or the storyboard?

Comment: @JasonNam Ok I will. Thanks! (:

Comment: What is the button title set in storyboard and what is the expected title on tap on it?

Comment: @Abhinav I was able to fix that problem but it appears that the likes display label and the button aren't changing correctly unless I give the table a complete refresh (delete everything in the table and append it back).

Answer (score 1):

You may try this, it worked for me.

call `tableView.reloadData()` just after refreshing your cell like :

```
....
 self.table.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)
 self.table.reloadData()
....
```

Doing this, does not mean to delete everything and append back as per your comment I guess!

**UPDATE**

Try changing the if block of `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as below:

```
 if self.liked.count < self.messages.count {
                        if (post["likers"] as! NSMutableArray).containsObject(PFUser.currentUser()!.objectId!) {
                            self.liked.append(true)
                            postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Unlike", forState: .Normal)

                        } else {
                            self.liked.append(false)
                            postCellObj.likeButton.setTitle("Like", forState: .Normal) //Add this line
                        }
                    }
```

Hope it will work for you!

Comment: Welcome. Glad to help you!

Comment: Actually it's not working. I just edited my code to what I have now. Could you see what may be going on?

Comment: Can't see table.reloadData() in your updated code. You better tell me what exactly not working

Comment: Well basically. I guess that line of code didn't fix it but I was able to figure all of that out above, but what's happening now is the likes is updating perfectly but now most of the time the like button isn't changing from like to unlike or vice versa.

Comment: Just tried this and the same thing is still happening. ):

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89554/discussion-between-irealme-and-john-doe).

Answer (score 0):

I think when the button is not changed, the case is belong the the last else block.

```
if showingMore[indexPath.row] {
        postCellObj.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        postCellObj.showAllAndLessButton.setTitle("Show Less", forState: .Normal)
        postCellObj.showAllAndLessButton.hidden = false

    }

    else if count(messageString) >= 800 {
        var messageNs = messageString as NSString
        var messageFinal = messageNs.substringWithRange(NSRange(location: 0, length: 800))
        postCellObj.message.text = messageFinal as String + "..."
        postCellObj.showAllAndLessButton.setTitle("Show All", forState: .Normal)
        postCellObj.showAllAndLessButton.hidden = false

    } else {
        postCellObj.message.text = messages[indexPath.row]
        // I think when the button is not changed, the case is belong to here
    }
```

Comment: What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Which title do you want to show when the showingMore is false and the messageString is less than 800 characters?

Comment: That function is unrelated it basically just says if the message (the main text of the post) is equal to or over 800 characters it cuts it off and puts a "..." at the end which the user can expand to see the entirety of and de-expand.